# How to clear a buffer in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm programming in assembler and I've created an auxiliary buffer to temporarily to store some characters and then write them to a file. The thing is that I have to use the auxiliary buffer several times so I need to clean/restore it and I don't know how to accomplish this.

I'm using i386 architecture with Linux.

PD: I forgot, this is how I have the buffer declared:

```
section .bss           
      auxBuffer resb 1000
```

Comment: no different than in any other language.

Comment: You're looking for `rep stosb`. Also, can't you re-use the same buffer without clearing it? If you're writing to it having already used the previous contents, why do you need to clear it?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar i need to write the content of the  buffer to a file, i just guess that if i re-use it many times without clearing it, can't i fill it and get an overflow?

Comment: @JamesFred : no, it won't. The buffer has a constant size.

Comment: Bytes aren't ever really "empty" in the first place, a buffer being empty just means that you don't care about the contents. It's not a physical state, it's your treatment of the thing.

Comment: You're clearly in need of an asm tutorial and manuals about how things work in general.  See the links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 2):

You clear a buffer by writing to it.
Obviously a location in memory is never truly empty, so clearing a buffer effectively means fill it with zero's.
There is nothing stopping you from filling it with [`0xCAFEBABE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) hex values, but zero's is the standard convention.

```
mov dword ptr [buffer],0
mov dword ptr [buffer+4],0
mov ...              +8],0
....
```

Obviously this is a silly way of clearing a buffer. If the buffer were 40,000 bytes you'd need 10,000 instructions; possible but wasteful.

Instead you write a loop and use a counter to keep track of what you've written so far.

```
mov ecx,10000        //10000 x 4 = 40.000 bytes
lea edx,[buffer]     //point edx to the start of the block to be cleared.  
xor eax,eax          //xor reg,reg is the same as mov reg,0, but faster.
@loop:
mov [edx+ecx*4],eax  //fill the buffer starting at the end.
dec ecx              //decrease the counter; also moving the destination.   
jnz @loop            //if ecx <> 0 (Non-Zero) then repeat.
ret                  //we are done, return.
```

`ecx` does double duty as a counter and as a pointer into the buffer.
Note that [`xor eax,eax`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XOR.html) is the standard way of setting a register to zero. It is both shorter than `mov eax,0` and faster because the CPU is hard-wired to give the former instruction preferential treatment.
There is however an even shorter way of doing this.
x86 has so called string instructions that accept a [`rep` (repeat) prefix](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html).
If thus prefixed the instruction will run `ecx` times.

```
push edi           //on Windows edi is non-volatile (callee-save), so save it.
lea edi,[buffer]   //edi is the start of the buffer.
xor eax,eax        //fill the buffer with zeros.
mov ecx,10000      
rep stosd          //store string with 10000 dwords = 40000 bytes.
pop edi            //restore edi to its previous value.
ret                //return.
```

[`stosd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html) (s̲t̲o̲re s̲tring per d̲word) uses `edi` as its D̲estination and `ecx` as the C̲ounter and `eax` as the source.
Note that `stosd` is a complex instruction. Modern x86 CPU's work faster with simple instructions and often an optimized (!) version of the second code snippet will work faster than a simple use of `rep stosd`.
*`rep stosd` moves forward by default on Windows/Linux. You can set up the CPU to make it move backwards, but then you'd have to restore the direction setting afterwards.*

Under windows `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are volatile and can be changed at will. All other registers need to be preserved between calls.

Comment: To get an idea of the optimized assembly code that would be used for clearing a buffer, compile a scratch C application that calls the `memset` function, and then inspect the disassembly. Note, however, that this is not really an operation that needs to be highly optimized. It makes more sense to optimize for size, rather than speed, so the string instructions are a pretty good bet being both reasonably quick and extremely short (byte-wise).